# Why is this not returning the expected ascending sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
month1 = 11
month2 = month1+1
months =[]

for i in range(5):
    months.append(month1)
    month1 = month2
print(months)
```

returns [11, 12, 12, 12, 12]

Not [11, 13, 14, 15, 16] as expected

Why does month2 variable not reset higher after each loop?

Comment: What do you mean "as expected"? Where in this code do you _change_ `month2`? Because the answer is "nowhere", so why would `month1` change? The first iteration updates it from 11 to 12, and then that's what it's going to be forever.

Comment: That `month2 = month1+1` at the start is *exactly* equivalent to `month2 = 12`.  You calculated a value and assigned it to a variable, you did not set up any sort of automatic recalculation.

Comment: Why isn't 12 in your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to increase it in the loop:

```
month = 11
months =[]

for i in range(5):
    months.append(month + i)
```

Answer (score 0):

at no point are you changing the value of month1 or month2 INSIDE the for loop/// so the month2=month1+1 needs to be inside the for loop for it to change and count up.

Answer (score 0):

For the first iteration, you can increase by 2 then increase 1-by-1.

```
month1 = 11
months = []

for i in range(5):
    months.append(month1)
    if i == 0:
        month1 += 2
    else:
        month1 += 1
print(months)
```

Result:

```
[11, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```